Creating capillaries with Geo nodes



I'm trying to create such an intricate capillary network in blender through geometry nodes but I am having a hard time figuring things out.
I trying to use the shortest path node but the result is a root-like structure. I'd want to have a start point from which all the arteries diverge and an end point where all of veins the converge.
The best I'm able to achieve is this:

What I had done was to use to shortest path node on a lattice and then mirror it. The current method is much inefficient. Since I'll have to have several instances of the same it will be very laggy.
I'm attaching the blend file.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!


It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

2d or 3d? Please give us some more detail.

@RickT Attached the file.

@DanielMöller, In 3D. Sorry I'm just a newbie here. Didn't realize I was being vague. Let me know if you need for more details. Thanks.

Hi, I closed as a duplicate of Geometry Nodes: How Can I make an Organic Vein system? - if this doesn't work for you, maybe [Edit] into your question how your case is different.
